# Why is my animation doing what I don't expect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to animate card dealing with CSS and jQuery.

I have positioned a single .png image of a card at the bottom of the window, and I want it to respond to a click event by spinning and moving to the top of the screen. While the card does do that, it doesn't stay at the x,y coordinates when the animation is done. It actually re-positions itself where it started at the bottom of the screen.

1. Why?
2. Am I just going about it stupidly?

```css
@-webkit-keyframes deal {

from {
}

to { 
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
    }
}

img {
position: absolute;}

.card {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: deal .2s 1 ;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.1,.35,.1,.85);
}
```

```
<img class='' id='card' src='img/b2fv.png' />
```

```
function placeElements(){
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var ch = $('#card').height();
    var cw = $('#card').width();
    var cx = (ww - cw)/2;
    var cy = (wh - ch);
    $('#card').css('left',cx); 
    $('#card').css('top',cy);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    placeElements();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        placeElements()
    });

    $("#card").on('click', function(){
        $(this).attr('class','card');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you animuson for fixing my poorly formatted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set animation's fill mode to `forwards`. Doing this will make the animated element hold the position of its final keyframe after the animation is complete.

From this [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

> **Fill mode: forwards**
>
> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe encountered depends on the value of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count

```
.card {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: deal .2s 1 ;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.1,.35,.1,.85);
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Add this and also the corresponding browser specific versions */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/B2tzT/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this without keyframes, by just using `transition` property

```
#card.card {
    left: 10px;
    top: 0px;    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
}
#card {
    -webkit-transition: all 5s;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/LE7JK/)**

Comment: Thank you for this also. I've been struggling with animations literally for years. I loathe keyframes!

Comment: +1 mate. This is also a good option but depends on the exact needs. I assume that the question is only a sample and there is actually more to it (which justifies use of keyframe animations) than what is posted here.

Comment: I think you're spot-on Harry. I am using the keyframe because I want to see 'tweening' between the two points. If I use this code I can get the card to rotate, but if I add translate() to the mix, it fails.